# Listing environment variables of a particular SHELL

Tags: command-line, users, environment-variables, session

Is it possible to list the environment variables set by a perticular shell session.

```
[root@me]who

dave     pts/1        Jan 23 03:09 (::ffff:132.39.129.11)
dave     pts/3        Jan 23 04:04 (::ffff:132.39.130.42)
patrick  pts/4        Jan 23 03:31 (::ffff:132.39.129.11)
patrick  pts/2        Jan 23 02:59 (::ffff:10.2.13.166)
jonh     pts/5        Jan 23 03:41 (132.39.130.8)
john     pts/6        Jan 23 03:53 (::ffff:132.39.130.42)
root     pts/0        Jan 23 04:04 (132.39.130.42:0)
```

I would like to know the environment variables that have been set in the sesssion on pts/4 let's say.

Thanks for the help,
Cheers

Comment: Just go to terminal and type export without arguments, Then Environment variables of that session will be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the process id you can receive the enviroment. You can use `ps -aux` to get the process id's of a given tty. When you have the process id you can use the command `sudo cat /proc/$PROCSSID/environ` where you replace `$PROCESSID` with the process id - to dump it's enviroment.

Comment: I was 5 secondes quicker :D but have an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

The environment is set to a process, not a TTY. 1 tty can have several shells active at the same time so can have different sets of variables.

So do a

```
ps -ef |grep pts/4
```

and note the processid of the shell you want to investigate. Then have a look at ...

```
more /proc/{processid}/environ
```

---

See `man proc 7` for more on this.

Answer (score 2):

There could be any (capable) process attached to the terminal, not necessarily a shell. But a shell is typical, and of course, there could be multiple shells involved -- imagine a shell spawns another one, and so on.

Linux kernel exposes part of it's internal data structure via the pseudo FS, `procfs`; mounted on `/proc` (default). A process's environment is typically exposed via the `/proc/PID/environ` file.

So, you can get the process(es) that is attached to a certain terminal, and then read the `/proc/PID/environ` file to get the process's environment. Also in the file, the variable values are shown as `KEY=VALUE` pair, and the variables separated from each other by ASCII NUL, so you need to handle that too for readability.

Getting the PID of all processes attached to the desired terminal and using `awk` to read the relevant environment file, and get the variables in newline separated form:

```
ps -eo pid,tty | awk -v tty='pts/4' '$2 ~ tty {"cat /proc/"$1"/environ" \
             | getline i; gsub("\\0", "\n", i); printf "PID=%s\n%s\n\n",$1, i}'
```

Use desired terminal name on `tty` variable passed to `awk`, here i have used `pts/4` like you mentioned in the question. The output will also contain a `PID=<pid>` line at start, just for sake of clarity, and readability.